# Why amazon web server don't use all the available resources to run python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running python code on AWS (EC2) to extract text from images.

When running the application on my laptop it takes 3 minutes to run, but when I run it on AWS Iget the same time of processing.
When I see the statistics, I see that AWS uses only 10% of cpu.

I even rewrote my code and introduced parallel processing using the python `multiprocessing` library and even did process inside process(no daemon processes) and I get always the same results.

So, my question is: Is there any configuration on AWS to let it use all  available resources?

Or, are they ways to modify the code to improve performance?

Comment: What Instance Type are you using? I suspect you are using a [T2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html) which has CPU credits. When you run out of CPU credits, CPU is limited to 10%. If you want faster performance, use a larger instance type or choose an instance from a different family (eg M4) that does not have restrictions.

Comment: We used g2.2xlarge instance.I don't think it has Credits because sometimes I get more than 10% CPU usage(up to 25%)

Comment: Aside from the T2 instances, there are no restrictions on CPU available on Amazon EC2 instances. It's possible that your code is waiting for something (eg disk I/O) -- check your CloudWatch statistics on your EBS volumes to see whether they are too slow (Look at "Queue Length", which should be low or zero).